# Taking a bite "at life" or "of life"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm thinking of a title for my blog post. Would you say: (I am) taking a bite "at life" or "of life"?

Does it make sense to use it if I mean to convey the message that I am making an effort to live life to the fullest, or does my title convey the message that I am only making a passing/momentary effort at living life to the max. (e.g. in the pursuit of an extreme sport event)?

Comment: I have often heard the idiom "Take a bit of life" used to encourage someone to live more fully. *Come on, take a bit of life, for once!*  The expectation is that the person will benefit from the experience, or will enjoy how they are feeling, and will therefore want to live more fully going forward.  So it is a momentary experience.  But since life is a series of such moments, it could result in long-term change of attitude. As for the risk of extreme sports, people live life to the fullest in different ways :)

Comment: I think all three options—"take a bite at life," "take a bite of life," and "take a bite out of life"—have a sense of brevity or passing engagement that doesn't match the idea of "living life to the fullest." If you mean to convey the idea of a fundamental change in your approach to experiencing life, you might do better with a phrase such as "Plunging into Life" or "Embracing Life" or even "Life and Me: A New Relationship."

Answer (score 2):

The idiom I know would be "Take a bite out of life."

Comment: Appreciate this, James.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is **[take a bite out of something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+bite+out+of)**

*To reduce something*

- Work is taking a bite out of his free time.

**Usage notes:** often used about money.

- Rising energy costs would take a bite out of people's wallets.

([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+bite+out+of))

Comment: +1 for more complete answer than mine.